# No Audio on Dell latitude 3410 with ubuntu 20

Tags: sound, dell

I've just installed ubuntu on my dell latitude 3410, but I cant get the audio working.
In the config, the audio output device says something like "fake output" and I see the bars moving when i play something on youtube. But there is no sound. Neither connecting the headphones. can anyone please help me? I've done this:

```
sudo apt install alsa-tools-gui
Run hdajackretask
Parser hints > jack_detect = no
Apply now
Install boot override
```

BUT in the left part of the screen there is message: "No codecs found"
Son I cant click "apply now" and "install boot override"

Thanks in advance.-

Comment: Update: Now it detects both of my sound devices, the realtek output and the HDMI sound output. When I select the HDMI out, I have sound. But when i select the realtek sound, the speakers don't work. I connect the headphones, the system detect that, it switches the sound device to "headphones... something" but there's no sound.

Comment: any solution me to having same problem on ubuntu 20.04

Answer (score 1):

The solution posted [here](https://www.linuxuprising.com/2018/06/fix-no-sound-dummy-output-issue-in.html) under the section [#2 Fix PCI/internal sound card not detected (dummy output) with Ubuntu kernel 5.3.0-41 and -42 in Ubuntu 19.10 / 18.04](https://www.linuxuprising.com/2018/06/fix-no-sound-dummy-output-issue-in.html) worked for me.

Just do this:

> 1. Edit `/etc/modprobe.d/alsa-base.conf` as root and add `options snd-hda-intel dmic_detect=0` at the end of this file.
>    Without comma, of course!

After this, restart!

Comment: This answer helped me to bring back the HDMI sound output. Thanks.